# moment.js is not updating the time, only shows the time when .js file was started

Tags: node.js, date, time, discord.js, momentjs

I'm trying to include actual date and time to the certain message, however I'm unable to do it, because `moment.js` keeps stucked at the same time. For some reason it only triggers the same time over and over again when script was started.

```
//require moment + time format
var moment = require('moment');
var todaymoment = moment().format('L, hh:mm:ssa');

//Check the current time each 5 seconds and update message
      setInterval(function () {
        message.edit({ embeds: [currentTime.setDescription('Current time is: ' + todaymoment) && currentTime.setTitle('Time Updated!')] })
        console.log(todaymoment)
      }, 5000)
  })
```

logs:

```
04/01/2022, 03:30:23am
04/01/2022, 03:30:23am
04/01/2022, 03:30:23am
04/01/2022, 03:30:23am
```

I also tried different library, but results are same.

Comment: Can you show the whole code?

Comment: There are too many things in the code, everything related to my `moment.js` problem is provided. I just need to know why the moment.js time is never updated, only when I restarted the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because you have initialised the var todayMoment once and you are just printing it again and again every timeout, you are not really getting a new time value every 5 seconds.

You could place your `var todaymoment = moment().format('L, hh:mm:ssa');` inside the setTimeout

To explain this you can see the jsFiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/kjzq567h/4/

Comment: Thank you! You're right, I needed to declare it in the actual function so it gets the real time. I feel really stupid hahah, again thank you! :-)